# Compare String to a wildcard pattern string in SQL database column

Tags: sql, compare, pattern-matching, wildcard

How would I compare a file name with a naming convention thats saved as a windows wildcard pattern in a SQL column? For example:

I have a file HCLA_MCLA_20220308 and I want to check if there is a wildcard naming convention that matches this file name in my File_Naming_Convention column of my table. The match should be for "*HCLA_MCLA_**"

[HCLA naming convention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC0iB.png)

All the naming conventions either use * or ?. The stars mean any number of characters before and/or any number or characters after. The ? means only 1 wild character in that position. Im not sure why there are two ** at the end of files in some cases.

My wildcard file naming convention column looks like this:
[Section of column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97qsP.png)

Now I tried a query like below but this doesn't seem to be working. It appears that the wildcard tokens in the SQL table are windows wildcards. In my query I tried to replace them with SQL equivalents.

```
Select * 
from MPM_FTP_Eligibility_Files_List 
where replace(File_Naming_Convention,'*','%') like 'HCLA_MCLA_20220308'
```

Update:
Here is the fix to take care of both * and ?. Needed to swap positions between my file name and like pattern in my query, as jarlh accurately pointed out.

```
Select * from MPM_FTP_Eligibility_Files_List where 'FCS-CA25_1_20220301_1000N_Cigna_W_Trans.txt' like replace(replace(File_Naming_Convention,'*','%'),'?','_')
```

Comment: The LIKE wildcards should be in the right-side argument.

Comment: I had that at first and I wasn't getting anything. So I swapped positions and didnt see a difference. Now when I swapped it worked. Hmm. Seems to be working now. Let me test it some more.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Underscores in SQL Server and Oracle for example are actually like your "?", a single wildcard character. So might need to escape the underscores in your search if you want to truly validate the entire file name

Comment: I'm using MS SQL. That's a good point.